# OWIN middleware doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin, middleware

I've recently started learning how to use Owin specification. I've added Owin packages, which are listed below to Web API 2 project. I've commented out the usage of WebApiConfig, and moved routes config and Elmah Logger to Startup class as you can see below -

```
Startup.cs - [assembly: OwinStartup("DataServicesStartup", typeof (Startup))]
public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll); 
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();                               
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", new {id = RouteParameter.Optional});
            config.Services.Add(typeof (IExceptionLogger), new ElmahExceptionLogger());
            ConfigureAuth(app);
            JwtConfig.ConfigureOAuth(app);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
```

Commented out WebApiConfig usage -

```
 protected void Application_Start()
            {
                WebLocatorIoC.RegisterServices();

                AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
                //GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
                FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
                RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
                BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            }
```

However, when I'm trying to go to specified routes nothing happens. For example when I try to make a request to Controllers/ValuesController I use localhost:1111/api/values. Also Owin.Cors doesn't seem to work too. Only when I use routing and Cors in WebApiConfig it works, in this case WebApi.Cors.

I have the following Owin packages installed:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin                                                                                                                 
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin                                            
Microsoft.Owin                                                                  
Microsoft.Owin.Cors.                                                               
Microsoft.Owin.Diagnostics                                                                                      
Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener                        
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb                                                                   
Microsoft.Owin.Hosting                                                                               
Microsoft.Owin.Security                                                                                  
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies                                         
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook                                                                      
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google                                                                             
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt                                                                                   
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Microsoft                                                                     
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth                                                                     
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter                                                                        
Microsoft.Owin.SelfHost                                                                                            
Ninject.Web.Common.OwinHost                                                                                                        
Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost                                                                                         
Owin
```

So, could someone please give me a hint about what I'm doing wrong.

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
        //Other action methods were omitted 
    }
```

Updates: added OWIN Startup Attribute.

Comment: Can you show the controller you are trying to hit and the route you are trying to connect to it with?

Comment: The route - "api/{controller}/{id}". And for example default values controller - api/values. It couldn't find any of the controllers.

Because, as far as I can understand, Owin doesn't handles - config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", new {id = RouteParameter.Optional});

Comment: It handles it fine. Can you show your controller?

Comment: Just as I mentioned before. Even a default ValuesController returns 404 status code. Added controller to a question.

Comment: And when you call you endpoint are you using a route ike this: http://yourdomain/api/values ? That's the part you are not showing and will help your question get answered. What you have in startup looks fine. It is not an issue with Owin just because you are not hitting the route. Can you show the code you are attempting to hit the route with?

Comment: Yes like that. Thanks, I've updated my question a bit. But still route is just I part of a problem. Cors doesn't seem to work too, as a part of Owin pipeline. When I use WebAPI.Cors in WebApiConfig it works, so it's really strange...

Comment: Also, is your Startup class decorated like this : - [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyApi.Startup))]

Comment: Derek's comment looks fine. Sounds like your Configuration method not called. If it's not, then you can find more info [here](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have the following line in the Startup.cs - 
[assembly: OwinStartup("DataServicesStartup", typeof (Startup))]

Comment: When you debug your code on app launch, does the Configuration method get 'Hit' in the Startup.cs. Have your tried debugging?

Comment: Yeah I've tried. It completely ignores breakpoints. That is why I'm thinking that Owin simply doesn't run.

Comment: That assembly reference should be outside the namespace, if there is one in your code?

Comment: After deploying on the server Owin started working as intended... The reason why it didn't worked still a mystery, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing at least one NuGet package.  You probably need Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core and you might want Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client to handle content negotiation.

Comment: Surprisingly, I have both of them installed. Thanks for help anyway.